# SQL Server Like function Query

Tags: sql-server

Can someone help me understand the difference between these 2 queries?

The output is different

```sql
Select distinct city 
from station 
where not city like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'

Select distinct city 
from station 
where city like '[^aeiou]%[^aeiou]'
```

Comment: There's a `^` in the second query's pattern matching string. Now you can search what that does (hint, it's documented in the `LIKE` operator's documentation).

Comment: First is: where `city` does *not* match the pattern of a vowel at beginning and end. Second one: `city` *does* match a pattern of two letters that are *not* vowels. Eg `'B'` will be returned by v1 not v2

Comment: The distributive rule for NOT will flip AND/OR operators. The first condition is effectively `NOT (city starts with a vowel AND city ends with a vowel)` which is equivalent to `(NOT city starts with a vowel) OR (NOT city ends with a vowel)` or `(city starts with a non-vowel) OR (city ends with a non-vowel)`. The second condition effectively `(city starts with a non-vowel) AND (city ends with a non-vowel)`. Close but not the same. (Length >= 2 is also a factor, but not relevant here.)

Comment: Correction: Length >= 2 is a relevant factor. The first condition expands to `NOT(... AND Length >= 2)` which reduces to `... OR Length < 2`. The second condition includes `... AND Length >= 2`. For both `city = 'a'` and `city = 'z'` condition #1 is true while condition #2 is false.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Data:***
Given the following table station:

| city |
| --- |
| orlando |
| atlanta |
| indianapolis |
| san fransisco |
| montreal |

***Case 1***
The following query returns the cities that start **and** end with a vowel like orlando, atlanta.

```sql
select city 
from station 
where city like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

***Case 2***
The following query returns the cities that don't start **and** don't end with a vowel like montreal.

```sql
Select city 
from station 
where city like '[^aeiou]%[^aeiou]'
```

***Case 3***
The following query returns the cities that:

1. don't start with a vowel like san fransisco and montreal **or**,
2. don't end with a vowel like indianapolis and montreal

```sql
select city 
from station 
where city not like '[aeiou]%[aeiou]'
```

Please note that in boolean algebra `Not(A And B)` is equivalent to `(Not A Or Not B)`

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5b9cf97d1472c9aab466bae96dbfdb9)